# laravel {{ $loop->index }} & jquery count++

Tags: jquery, laravel

Using the Laravel blade template, is there a way to include a variable and increase each time in the foreach, or what is the better approach?

[image: demo]

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link href="{{ asset('themes/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('themes/fontawesome/css/all.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('themes/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="d-flex min-vh-100 justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column">
    @foreach($colors as $color)
        <div id="showFilters">
            <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control mb-5" name="filters[{{ $loop->index }}][name]" value="{{ $color->color_code }}">
        </div>
    @endforeach
    <a id="addFilter" class="bg-primary text-white pt-2 pb-2 pe-3 ps-3 rounded-circle cursor-pointer">
        <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
    </a>
</div>
<script src="{{ asset('themes/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('themes/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    let count = 0;
    $('#addFilter').click(function () {
        count++;
        let html = '<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control mb-5" name="filters['+count+'][name]">';
        $('#showFilters').append(html);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: fyi, that's invalid code. You have multiple elements with the same `id="showFilters"`. `id` attributes _must_ be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible. If you have a normal collection/array the key equals the index and you can write the `foreach` loop like that:

```
@foreach($colors as $key => $color)
```

And then use it like: `name="filters[{{$key}}][name]"`

If you have a named array you can use a `for(each)` loop and include some php `@php` to define and increment a variable.

```
@php
  $counter = 0;
@endphp
@foreach($colors as $color)
  .....
  @php
    $counter++;
  @endphp
@endforeach
```

You will also neet to create unique ids like: `id="name-{{$key}}"`.
So that in your jquery code you can get the correct key from the id. Or you could look into data-attributes.

Comment: I tried both of the above codes but it did not work  https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4YBC.png

Comment: Look at the comment above you have a problem with the elments ids